# Node.js Data in the body not being saved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

All my projects were working fine before but all of sudden the content of the body is not being saved as if the body is not being parsed or something. Just to check I created this simple project of book directory but no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');
// import bodyParser from "body-parser";//for typscript code only, use require for js
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var bookRouter = require('./routes/books_routes');

const url = config.mongoURL;
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);

connect.then((DB)=>{
  console.log("Connected With the MongoDB Server");
},(err)=>{next(err)})
.catch((err)=>next(err));

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); //Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/books',bookRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Route File**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose =require('mongoose');
const Books = require('../models/books');

const bookrouter = express.Router();
// bookrouter.use(bodyparser.json());
bookrouter.use(express.json()); 

bookrouter.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
})); //Parse URL-encoded bodies

bookrouter.route('/')
.get((req,res,next)=>{
    Books.find({})
    .then((books)=>{
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('content-Type','application/json');
        res.json(books);
    },(err)=>{next(err)})
    .catch((err)=>next(err))
})
.post((req,res,next)=>{
    var book = new Books({
        book_name: req.body.book_name,
        book_author: req.body.book_author,
        book_description: req.body.book_description
    })
    book.save()
    .then((book)=>{
        Books.findById(book._id)
        .then((book)=>{
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
            res.json(book);
        },(err)=>next(err))
        })
})
.put((req,res,next)=>{
    res.send("PUT request is not supported at this API");
})
.delete((req,res,next)=>{
    Books.remove({})
    .then((resp)=>{
        res.statusCode=200;
        res.setHeader('content-type','application/json');
        res.send(resp);
    })
})
module.exports = bookrouter;
```

**Model file**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportlocalmongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var Books = new Schema({
    book_name :{
        type:String
    },
    book_author:{
        type:String
    },
    book_description:{
        type:String
    }
},{
    timestamps:true
})

Books.plugin(passportlocalmongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Book',Books);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "books-directory",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.10",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.7",
    "mongoose-currency": "^0.2.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: lines containing bodyparsar are commented out because it shows deprecated, instead used express.json()

Comment: So, it is not able to save data in DB ?

Comment: Yes, the data is not being saved in the DB and also when I perform a post request using postman no data is shown on it after the request is made successful.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the DB because whenever I make a post request an ID is added in the database. I think the problem is with the body of the request, the body is not being fetched/parsed or something.

Comment: try removing `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()` from the route file because it is already declared in the `app.js` file.

Comment: okay ill do that.

Comment: Same output nothing changed  : (

Comment: Try, adding your `body-parser` middleware above your `routes`

Comment: It shows body-parser deprecated.

Comment: Is it possible that my versions are out dated and have to be updated?

Comment: Yeah, `body-parser` is deprecated you need to use `express.json()` and `express urlencoded` . But did you tried moving your these middleware above to your routes ?